# Using Foreman to install packages

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, foreman

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server running Foreman and Puppet (as the master), and some other Ubuntu 14.04 machines which are Puppet nodes. I want to use Foreman to make sure the Puppet nodes have certain packages installed. With regular Puppet, you can include something like

```
package { "screen":
    ensure => "installed"
}
```

which triggers an apt command and installs screen. But I'm not sure how to do this with Foreman. Is it even possible? I haven't found any references to it, and all of my search results have some up with how to install Foreman itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I don't use Foreman, I use hiera. The examples should give you an idea what an ENC is for, not provide a complete howto for using Foreman. Here's [one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-foreman-to-manage-puppet-nodes-on-ubuntu-14-04) that covers the basics.

Second, Puppetlabs provides a similar site to this one for puppet specific questions, so you might want to look [there for help](http://ask.puppetlabs.com/questions/).

On to your question:

Foreman is, like hiera, an [external node classifier (ENC)](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/external_nodes.html). That means, that you can use it to attach classes to be loaded or variables to a node to be used by loaded classes.

What you still should (and have to) do, is to provide puppet with modules and manifests to load.

So an example would be writing a module named `misc`, put in `/etc/puppet/environment/prod/modules/misc`.

```
class misc {
    package { "screen":
        ensure => "installed"
    }
}
```

You can use Foreman to attach the class `misc` to sample nodes `node01.example.com` and `node02.example.com` to install screen on both nodes.

Another example using variables:

```
class misc(
  $packages = [ "screen" ],
) {
    package { $packages:
        ensure => "installed"
    }
}
```

You can use Foreman to attach the class `misc` to sample nodes `node01.example.com` and `node02.example.com`, and set the variable `misc::packages` to something like `[ "vim", "screen", "telnet" ]` to make it install vim, screen and telnet on both nodes.